# How does the constant e relate to continuously compound interest?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms, compound-interest

I understand the continuously compound interest formula and I've seen the proof that relates it to e but what I don't understand is how could someone think that e and $(1+1/n)^n$ are related? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: That depends on how you’re defining $e$ to begin with. A lot of people _define_ $e$ as the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The intuition is that the natural logarithm is $n\ln (1+1/n)$ where $$\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac1t\,dt.$$ You can prove this using properties of integrals, without the need to know the function is a logarithm. But it is fairly easy to see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_1^{1+1/n}f(t)\,dt=f(1)$$ for any continuous $f.$

Comment: So you get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log(1+1/n)=1.$$ Then you need to know that $\ln$ is continuous, increasing, and unbounded to know that $(1+1/n)^n\to\alpha$ for the unique value $\alpha$ such that $\ln\alpha=1.$

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuA2EAgAegE Section after intro

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've seen the actual proof, a good intuition for why $e$ and compound interest should be related comes from one of the most important properties that makes $e$ a special number: the fact the value of $e^t$ at a given $t = t_0$ is exactly the slope of the curve $e^t$ at $t = t_0$.

To get the intuition, consider what happens if, starting with $x(0) = 1\$$, you have a compound rate of $1$ with a given frequency of compounding $n$. What should happen when your frequency of compounding increases indefinitely? In other words, if you adjust the slope of $x(t)$ every time $x(t)$ changes, how should you adjust it?

Comment: It would be adjusted according to the continuously compound interest formula, but why should it be the same e in calculus?

Comment: The starting slope $m_0$ is $x(0)$ (i.e. $1$). If your interest does not compound, at every time $t$ you have $x(t) = x(0) + m_0 \cdot t = 1 + 1t$, which is just the equation of a line.
 
Now imagine compounding interest. Every time $t$ the interest is recalculated, you change the slope of the line to exactly $x(t)$. If you compound *continuously*, your $x(t)$ will have to be a function with a slope exactly equal to $x(t)$ at any time $t$. The only nontrivial function with such a property is $e^x$. And that property of $e$ is precisely what makes this number so special in calculus.